# Overloaded operator is never called in C++

Tags: c++, overloading, equals, copy-constructor

I'm writing a math library as a practical exercise. I've run into some problems when overloading the = operator. When I debuged it, I noticed that the call to vertex1 = vertex2 calls the copy constructor instead.

In the header file I have:

```
//constructors
vector3();
vector3( vector3 &v );
vector3(float ix, float iy, float iz);

//operator overloading
vector3 operator =(vector3 p);
....
```

In the source file I implemented:

```
vector3 vector3::operator =(vector3 p)
{
    vector3 v3;
    v3.x = p.x;
    v3.y = p.y;
    v3.z = p.z;
    return v3;
}
```

Later on I have a crossproduct method, and I want to use it like so:

```
vector3 v3;
v3 = v1.crossProduct(v2);
```

The error message is:
    error: no matching function for call to `vector3::vector3(vector3)'
but I do not want to call the copy constructor.

Comment: There's no need to have a copy-constructor/assignment-operator if all you need is bit-exact copy.

Comment: By the way, **why** don’t you want to call the copy constructor?

Comment: There is really no point posting non-compilable snippets. Technically the only thing that stops your code from compiling, when relevant bits are filled in, is the missing **const** which James points out. Of course, it won't do the right thing, since assignment operator is supposed to assign to `*this` (the left-hand value), not a temporary which gets thrown away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are mistakes in your code. Your copy-constructor must take a `const&`. The reference will avoid making a copy (which you wouldn't be able to do, being the copy-constructor), and it should be `const` since you're not modifying it:

```
vector3(const vector3&);
```

Temporary variables can be bound to `const&`, but *cannot* be bound to a mutable reference. That is, with your code you could do:

```
vector3 a;
vector3 b(a);
```

but not:

```
vector3 a(some_calculation()); // some_calculation returns a vector3
```

Additionally, your `operator=` is incorrect. Like the copy-constructor, it should generally take a `const&`, *but it should return a reference to `this`*. That's how chaining works:

```
int a, b, c;
a = b = c = 0;
// a.operator=(b.operator=(c.operator=(0)));
```

Returning a temporary is unorthodox, and doesn't accomplish anything. In your case, you could assign over and over and never change the value. **Weird**:

```
vector 3 a, b;
a = b; // doesn't change a...?!
```

`operator=` needs to change `this`.

Comment: I see what you mean... The header file with the method definitions was provided to the students... But I see that returning a temporary is strange. I will change my class, thanks a lot.

Comment: I was typing my answer then GMan posted this. While everyone here, including myself, is correct and was trying to tell you the same thing, I think this is the best, most clear, answer of the bunch.

Comment: You posted "The reference is typically suggested to avoid making a copy", but in the case of the copy constructor, the parameter MUST BE a reference. If it wasn't a reference, the parameter to the copy constructor would have to be copied, and copying means calling the copy constructor. See the problem?

Comment: @Fred: Fix'd indeed. My answer originally only had `operator=` in it (prior to posting), and I added copy-ctor in-place of `operator=`; didn't remove "suggested".

Answer (score 2):

> > vector3( vector3 &v );

That really should be `vector3( const vector3 &v );`

Since your return a temporary value, you must call a copy-constructor which takes a const reference.

Answer (score 2):

> I do not want to call the copy constructor.

What you want is irrelevant. You *need* a copy constructor here. `operator =` doesn’t get called in this situation, the copy constructor is. Besides, the signature is wrong, it should be

```
vector3& operator =(vector3 const& other);
```

The argument may also be passed in by value (but this is an advanced trick …) but the *return value* really *must* be a non-const reference.

(The signature of your copy constructor is also unconventional, see James’ answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Make `vector3 vector3::operator =(vector3 p)` use references instead so you don't need to create a copy.

```
vector3& vector3::operator =(vector3& p);
```

You didn't want to create a copied object in the first place anyway.

Comment: No, no joy. I want to create a copy, so the operator can act like it would with, for instance, an integer.

Comment: @pypman: That's incorrect. It's well established that `operator=` returns a reference to `*this`.

Comment: @GMan: removed the `return` lapsus

Comment: Alright. Sorry about that. I tried to add the reference, however, now I get the error: no match for 'operator=' in 'v3 = vector3::crossProduct(const vector3&) const(((const vector3&)((const vector3*)(&v2))))' but crossProduct returns a vector3 object. Am I using it wrong?

Comment: @honk: You should be taking a `const&`, since you're not modifying the argument. (which also let's you be assigned temporary values)

Comment: @GMan: sure, didn't mention it since it is unrelated to his problem

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice in C++ to do one of two things depending on whether you want your object copyable (i.e assignable to another variable) or not.  If you do you need to provide both the assign operator and the copy constructor.  For example:

```
class Point
{
public:
    Point ()                          { }
    Point (int x, int y)              : mX(x), mY(y) { }
    Point (const Point& p)            : mX(p.mX), mY(p,mY) { }

    Point& operator = (const Point& p)    { mX = p.mX; mY = p.mY; return *this; }

    int X () const                    { return mX; }
    int Y () const                    { return mY; }

private:
    int mX;
    int mY;
};
```

If you don't want it copyable you can put the prototype of both the copy constructor and the assign operator in a private section and do not provide an implementation.  Any attempt to copy it then will give a compiler error.

Whenever you use this kind of code:

```
Point P = anotherP;
```

the copy constructor will be called.  If you use this type of code:

```
Point P;
P = anotherP;
```

the assign operator will be called.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you "pass by value", as you are in your definition of operator =, a copy of the type is made for use a as local value to the method. Your operator isn't being called because the system cannot find a contructor that takes vector3 -- you've defined a copy constructor that takes vector3&.

Therefore, as others have stated, what you want to do is define your operator = as taking

`const vector3& p`

You should also update your declared copy constructor to take const vector3 also.